# Screen recorder fails to record screen and records black screen

Tags: audio, video, display, recording

I tried to record screen for recording a video  which was embedded in an application. The screen recorder used was **snagit**. Video is recorded, but only **black screen** gets recorded.

The same application was available on Play Store, and I tried recording the screen using various apps, but again only thing to be recorded was **black screen**.

It seems something within the application causes the video to be **hidden** and not be able to be recorded by screen recorders.

**Q**. Are videos inside the application really impossible to record?

**Q**. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: It might be useful if you added information about the application.  That would allow readers who have it to see what's going on and maybe look behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways things can be rendered to screen (without getting technical), that mean capture wont always be compatible. I get the problem with screenshots sometimes.

You might try this program. It has several different methods of capture so one of them may work
https://obsproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the video you want to record has a protection function that prevents you from recording.